# How to get an image displayed in second column when clicking a radio button?

Tags: html, image, radio-button

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Project 1.6</title>
<body>
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>
  <form>
   <input type= "radio" value = "Argentina" name = "places">Argentina<br>
   <input type= "radio" value = "Australia" name = "places">Australia<br>
   <input type= "radio" value = "Bolivia" name = "places">Bolivia<br>
   <input type= "radio" value = "Cuba" name = "places">Cuba<br>
   <input type= "radio" value = "Findland" name = "places">Findland<br>
   <input type= "radio" value = "France" name = "places">France<br>
   <input type= "radio" value = "Italy" name = "places">Italy<br>
   <input type= "radio" value = "Peru" name = "places">Peru<br>
   <input type= "radio" value = "Syria" name = "places">Syria<br>
   <input type= "radio" value = "Tunisia" name = "places">Tunisia<br>
  </form>
  </td>
  <td>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

So, basically I want that whenever i click on a radio button in the first column, I get the image of the location's flag in the second column? 
*In HTML please.*

Comment: HTML is a *Mark Up Language*. It is not functional, it's purpose is to describe a documents' layout. Generally to a browser. To respond to button clicks you need to use a browser side scripting language (javascript) or serverside programing language. Also What second column? Where are the flag images?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use JavaScript for this. Make an hidden div for each option in second column and make particular one visible with JavaScript on option select.

Answer (score 0):

Some what ugly **CSS** solution, as I mentioned in my comment above this can't be done in pure HTML, this is as close as you'll get.

```css
.flag 
{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 150px;
    display:none;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + .flag {display: inline-block;}
```

```html
<input type= "radio" value = "Argentina" name = "places">Argentina <img src="https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/graphics/flags/large/ar-lgflag.gif" class="flag"><br>
<input type= "radio" value = "Australia" name = "places">Australia<img src="https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/graphics/flags/large/as-lgflag.gif" class="flag"><br>
<input type= "radio" value = "Bolivia" name = "places">Bolivia<img src="https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/graphics/flags/large/bl-lgflag.gif" class="flag"><br>
<input type= "radio" value = "Cuba" name = "places">Cuba<img src="https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/graphics/flags/large/cu-lgflag.gif" class="flag"><br>
<input type= "radio" value = "Findland" name = "places">Findland<img src="https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/graphics/flags/large/fi-lgflag.gif" class="flag"><br>
```

This is dependant on the [Adjacent Sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) so you can't move the image to a seperate table cell.

Or if you prefere cleaner HTML with slightly more complex CSS:

```css
.flag 
{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 150px;
    display:none;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked ~ .flag {display: inline-block;}

input[value="Argentina"]:checked ~ .flag{
    background-image:url("https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/graphics/flags/large/ar-lgflag.gif");
}

input[value="Australia"]:checked ~ .flag{
    background-image:url("https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/graphics/flags/large/as-lgflag.gif");
}

input[value="Bolivia"]:checked ~ .flag{
    background-image:url("https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/graphics/flags/large/bl-lgflag.gif");
}

input[value="Cuba"]:checked ~ .flag {
    background-image:url("https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/graphics/flags/large/cu-lgflag.gif");
}

input[value="Findland"]:checked ~ .flag {
    background-image:url("https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/graphics/flags/large/fi-lgflag.gif");
}
```

```html
<input type= "radio" value = "Argentina" name = "places">Argentina<br>
<input type= "radio" value = "Australia" name = "places">Australia<br>
<input type= "radio" value = "Bolivia" name = "places">Bolivia<br>
<input type= "radio" value = "Cuba" name = "places">Cuba<br>
<input type= "radio" value = "Findland" name = "places">Findland<br><div class="flag"></div>
```